# Rename fails because it represents a path or device name

Tags: powershell

When I run the following command:

```
Rename-Item some\long\path\fileName.txt some\long\path\newName.txt
```

I receive the following error message:

> Cannot rename the specified target, because it represents a path or device name.

I've tried wrapping the paths in quotes and that doesn't succeed either.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For the second argument, **just use the new name not the full path**. That is, do this:

```
Rename-Item some\long\path\fileName.txt newName.txt
```

[From the docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849763.aspx), it says of `-NewName<String>`

> Enter only a name, not a path and name. If you enter a path that is different from the path that is specified in the Path parameter, Rename-Item generates an error.

Answer (score 6):

For me the issue was different

The file name was the issue:

I have tried to put the following file name:

> Old_2016-02-17T13:52:28_Stage1.txt

But only After changing it to:

> Old_17022016_0154_Stage1.txt

it worked

Comment: same for me. i was trying to use ":" in the name. if you try to do it in GUI it will tell you that ":" is an illegal character. i wish the error on the 'rename-item' cmdlet would have this error mapped correctly. would have saved me a lot of trouble...

Answer (score 0):

In case you came across this question after trying to batch rename files as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_ -replace 'Old','New'} # MAY FAIL!
```

You might get the following error:

> Rename-Item: Cannot rename the specified target, because it represents a path or device name

As an example, assume you have a file `C:\MyFullPath\MyFile.txt` and run the following commands:

```
cd C:\MyFullPath
ls | ren -NewName {$_ -replace 'My','Your'}
```

The command is using `$_` as content on which to operate. `$_` provides the full path of the file, not only its name. The command now tries to find the pattern `My` in `C:\MyFullPath\MyFile.txt`.

The file matches the specified pattern `My` and so does the parent path of the file. Hence, the command tries to rename the full file name to `C:\YourFullPath\YourFile.txt`. That is, it also tries to rename the parent path of the file. That is what causes the error.

The solution is to use `$_.Name` instead of `$_`.
Here's the proper way to rename files:

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'Old','New'}

# or short (don't use this in scripts):
ls | ren -n {$_.Name -replace 'Old','New'}
```